# Character encoding issue between logstash and logstash-forwarder

Tags: amazon-web-services, character-encoding, logstash

I have the following setup -

```
[logstash-forwarder nodes] -> [Amazon's elastic load balancer] -> [logstash nodes]
```

I start logstash-forwarder with the following config file -

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": ["<Load_balancer_DNS_name>:443"],
    "ssl key": "/etc/pki/private/logstash-forwarder.key",
    "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "timeout": 15
  },

  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [ "-" ],
      "fields": { "type": "stdin" }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I start logstash with following settings -

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => "7286"
    codec => plain {
      charset => "UTF-8"
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch {
    host => "<cluster_node_ip>"
    protocol => "http"
  }
}
```

Now I feed some input at the command line from logstash-forwarder just to see if it is reachable perfectly at logstash. So when I type "Hello World" or just any other plain text on the logstash-forwarder side, I receive the following on logstash node, instead of the original text -

````
Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. {:text=>"1W\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u00011C\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000ox^2ta```\\u0004bV fI\\xCB\\xCCI\\u0005\\xF1uA\\x9C\\x8C\\xFC\\xE2\\u0012 -\\x90Y\\xA0kh\\xA0kha\\xAAkdh\\xACkb\\u0006\\u0014c\\xCBOK+N\\u0005\\xC92\\u001A\\x80\\x94\\xE6d\\xE6\\x81\\xF4\\t\\xBBy\\xFA9\\xFAć\\xB8\\u0006\\x87\\xC4{{:9\\xFA9\\xDAۃ\\xA4K*\\v@Ҭ\\xC5%)\\x99y\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\xFF\\xFF\\u0001\\u0000\\u0000\\xFF\\xFF\\u001A\\x93\\u0015\\xA2", :expected_charset=>"UTF-8", :level=>:warn}
````

Comment: try switching for charset => "ISO-8859-1" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

logstash-forwarder uses a unique protocol to communicate with logstash, named 'lumberjack'.

You need to have the key & crt on the logstash server as well, and use a *lumberjack* input to handle it:

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    # The port to listen on
    port => 7286

    # The paths to your ssl cert and key
    ssl_certificate => "path/to/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "path/to/logstash-forwarder.key"

    # Set this to whatever you want.
    type => "somelogs"
  }
}
```

What you're seeing is the encrypted lumberjack messages.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder#use-with-logstash